# Unable to locate package sqlite3

Tags: 12.10

I am trying to run

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package sqlite3
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just saw that your command is not complete. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

If still does not work, try the following:

Running the command:

```
 sudo apt-cache policy sqlite3
```

will give you the following output:

```
sqlite3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.7.9-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

It is visible that the package is in archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Hence, check your repositories. Open the update manager, go to settings, and after typing your password, you will see the repositories selected:

[image]

Try the options I have selected, and you should be fine.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to read `apt-cache policy`

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. Actually it's quite simple. I need to do a do a software update first (since this is a new install)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade # Update software
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev # Install packages
```