# How install sqlite3 from scratch

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation, sqlite

I'm trying to install sqlite3 in Ubuntu 12.04. I tried `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` but I get the following error:

```
tanvir@TanvirPC:~$ 'sqlite3' is currently not installed. You can install it by  
typing: sudo apt-get install sqlite3
tanvir@TanvirPC:~$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
[sudo] password for tanvir:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3.0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1) but 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 is to  
be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried the answers to [Unable to locate package sqlite3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208393/need-help-installing-sqlite3) without success.

Comment: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/230619/cannot-install-sqlite3?rq=1) also does not work. Running command `sudo apt-get install sqlite3-0:i386` shows `E: FindIndex failed` error.

Comment: Might help to add the information from: apt-cache policy sqlite3 libsqlite3-0; My guess would be you have the lib from -updates but then you disabled it somehow so it is trying to install sqlite3 from -release which can't satisfy the dep. Check software-properties-gtk and on the Updates tab make sure 'Recommended Updates' is checked, and if not check it and run: sudo apt-get update; then try installing again.

Comment: sqlite3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.7.9-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
libsqlite3-0:
  Installed: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.7.9-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
@JasonConti

Comment: Great Brother! @JasonConti. It worked. :-) Thanks for your great help. Please Give an answer so that I can upvote it and hit the accept button to give you some points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  a-package: Depends: other-package (= version-in-release) but version-in-updates is to
             be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

occurs with a package requiring a version of another package from the *-release* archive (the Ubuntu repositories frozen at the time an Ubuntu version is released), but it says it wants to install a version from the *-updates* archive, it usually means that the version from *-updates* is already installed.

This can be verified by running `apt-cache policy other-package` and checking which repository provided the package. In this case:

```
libsqlite3-0:
Installed: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1
Candidate: 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1

Version table:
  *** 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      3.7.9-2ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages
```

We see that `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status` is the only line for the installed package, showing that it is manually installed. This can happen either when the *-updates* repository is disabled, or occasionally when some mirrors go out of date.

The *-updates* repository can be enabled again by running `software-properties-gtk`, verifying that on the *Updates* tab that `Recommended Updates` is checked, and then running `sudo apt-get update`.